# How to render one component multiple times and show the result one after the other?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, render

This is what I want to have:

```
Jake J.
Matt D.
Kate K.
Matt H.
```

What I get is this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUlZn.png)
And here is my code

```
renderNames(){
   const names =[
     "Jake J.",
     "Matt D."
     ...
   ]
   names.map((name,i) = > 
      return ( 
        <div><b>{name}</b></div>
   )
   return names;
}
```

And then in the render method I call this.renderNames(). And the names are shown one on top of the other and I don't know what should I do so that they are shown one after the other(as shown above).
I'm using Meteor + React + TypeScript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` [doesn't mutate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array. Your function returns the array of strings, not an array of divs. Do this instead:

```
renderNames(){
   const names = [
     "Jake J.",
     "Matt D.",
     ...
   ];
   return names.map(name => <div><b>{name}</b></div>);
}
```

Comment: It does't work I still have the same problem see image in the post I just edited.

Comment: I see, that's an entirely different problem. Probably something CSS-related.

Comment: Yes you are right. I deleted the <b></b> and everything is ok.Thanks I lot.